# Handling exit status in Bash

Tags: bash

Can anyone come up with a shorter implementation of the function *test* below (which prints the same error message and has the same exit status)?

```
function test
{
   some-command
   exit_status=$?
   if [ $exit_status -ne 0 ]; then
      echo "some-command failed with exit status $exit_status" >&2
   fi
   return $exit_status
}
```

Comment: You should probably not be overriding the built-in `test` command.

Comment: You probably want this: `echo "msg" >&2`

Answer (score 1):

```
some-command || echo "some-command failed with exit status $?" >&2
```

If you want to capture and return the exit status, do

```
function test { 
   some-command || r=$? && echo "some-command failed with exit status $r" >&2 && return $r 
}
```

Comment: Or as a function, `try () { "$@" && return 0; local r; r=$?; echo "$@ failed with exit status $r" >&2; return $r; }`

Comment: @January: The exit status of this (compound) command is always 0, so it does not have the same behavior as the function test.

Comment: OK, see the modified version.

Answer (score 1):

Return immediately if the command succeeds. Then, if you haven't returned, you know there was an error. This eliminates the need for the `if` statement.

```
function newTest {
    some-command && return 0
    exit_status=$?
    echo "some-command failed with exit status $exit_status" >&2
    return $exit_status
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

test () {
    "$@" || eval "echo '$1 failed with exit status $?' >&2; exit $?" 
}
```

Hope this helps =)

Comment: It should have been >&2 (redirection to stderr). Thanks for pointing it out, I have corrected it now.

Comment: Ok, I now edited my answer to account for that =)

Answer (score 0):

if you are not super picky about what exactly is logged on error and are always terminating the script on error then bullet-proof way of achieving what you need is

```
set -e
```

added to the very beginning of your script.

from "help set":

```
  -e  Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status.
```

Comment: `set -e` terminates the shell. Quite useless for a test script, which probably has to perform many different tests.